# Create multi-line chart on Kibana vega with legend based on inner buckets key values

Tags: kibana, vega-lite, vega, kibana-7

I had a query response providing the data of format

```
{
          "key_as_string": "2022-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1646006400000,
          "doc_count": 2070,
          "count": {
            "doc_count": 3992,
            "categories_count": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": 1,
                  "doc_count": 3070
                },
                {
                  "key": 5,
                  "doc_count": 316
                },
                {
                  "key": 3,
                  "doc_count": 178
                },
                {
                  "key": 0,
                  "doc_count": 26
                },
                {
                  "key": 7,
                  "doc_count": 26
                },
                {
                  "key": 6,
                  "doc_count": 20
                },
                {
                  "key": 2,
                  "doc_count": 10
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

How do I create a multi-line chart with legends that based each key value as one line and
y-axis is the `doc_count` and x-axis is the `key_as_string` time. I also need to handle the case that inner buckets will not output empty key count (missing key values that have count 0), but the key can be only in range of 0-7.

Answer (score 0):

To create a multi-line chart refer to the [gallery](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/). This is a [line chart](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/line-chart/). My advice, look around the gallery for things you want to include in your visualisation and extract those pieces, don't forget to refer to the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/) too.

For the 0 bucket, this is something I've encountered before. Try doing the [term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) before the [date_histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html). The date_histogram aggregation produces buckets for 0 counts whereas the term does not.